# How to add a new node to a NodeList using Perl (XML::LibXML)

Tags: xml, perl, libxml2

I'm trying to add a new node to an existing XML document.

However, trying to use the push function in a [XML::LibXML::NodeList](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/XML%3a%3aLibXML%3a%3aNodeList) result does not change the document.

Here's an example:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl 
use strict;
use XML::LibXML;

my $parser     = XML::LibXML->new();
my $xml_string =
'<example>
    <books>
        <category id="1">
            <book isbn="a" />
            <book isbn="b" />
            <book isbn="c" />
        </category>
        <category id="2"/>
        <category id="3"/>
    </books>
</example>';
my $doc = $parser->parse_string($xml_string);
my $category_nodelist = $doc->findnodes('//category[@id="1"]');

my $book_el = $doc->ownerDocument->createElement('book');
$book_el->setAttribute("isbn", "d");
$category_nodelist->push($book_el);

print $doc->toString(1);
```

Comment: Don't link to the exact [User/version URL](http://search.cpan.org/~shlomif/XML-LibXML-1.89/lib/XML/LibXML/NodeList.pm). Instead use one of the permalinks [search.cpan.org/perldoc/...](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/XML::LibXML::NodeList) [metacpan.org/module/...](http://metacpan.org/module/XML::LibXML::NodeList) [p3rl.org](http://p3rl.org/XML::LibXML::NodeList). ( Unless you need to use a specific version )

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To insert the new node into the document, use

```
$category_nodelist->[0]->appendChild($book_el);
```

Answer (score 1):

Please note that XML is a TREE-based data structure. `XML::LibXML` is a libxml2 parser to construct the tree data structure from a XML data. 
 `XML::LibXML::NodeList` is a LIST of nodes matching your search criteria. So, adding a new node to this list will not make any change to the XML.

To add a new node, first find the node from your nodelist and call the suitable sub

```
appendChild
addChild
addSibling
```

and many more. Hope this will be helpful to you.

Answer (score 0):

A quick perusal of The Fine Manual makes me think that you should be using the [DOM interface](http://p3rl.org/XML%3a%3aLibXML%3a%3aDOM), not push and pop (which do nothing more than modifying the list, not the underlying DOM, as you found out).